# Why is the "Build an image" step failing for Docker on Visual Studio Online?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to build a Docker image, which seems to build and run fine on my local machine, but it keeps failing with the following error:

> 2018-05-06T13:56:15.2331697Z failed to register layer: re-exec error: exit status 1: output: ProcessUtilityVMImage C:\ProgramData\docker\windowsfilter\3b555fe81a5123419e06c66652d9e73adbbb17b10f52ddd9f59da3b7fb87adab\UtilityVM: The system cannot find the path specified.
>   2018-05-06T13:56:15.2531044Z ##[error]C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe failed with return code: 1

It fails on the "Build an Image" step.  I'm trying to use an Azure registry type.

I'm trying to set up Continuous Deployment using Visual Studio Online.  I selected the Hosted 2017 build agent (but have tried other ones with no success there either).

My app is a .Net Core app.  I think it's trying to use a Nano Server, and from what I read, that might be part of the problem (maybe the Hosted agent doesn't support the Nano Server).

All of these technologies (.NET Core, Docker, Nano Server) are new to me (and probably new to mostly everyone), so I'm limited in my knowledge about them and where to start troubleshooting.

Any ideas?

[image: Uploaded Docker Ignore File]

The step of the Docker file that it's failing on is this one

> FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0-nanoserver-1709 AS base

Comment: Do you have any files in a .dockerignore file that aren't being included into the image?

Comment: @ErtySeidohl I just added an image of the .dockerignore file.  I don't think any of them should be included into the build of the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not supported on Hosted agent of VSTS, check this issue: [Docker images based on nanoserver-1709 not building on hosted VS2017 agent](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-image-generation/issues/85)

Comment: I ended up needing to use "FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-sdk"