# VSTS build fails when making a simple container

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am getting a:

> The following Docker images are incompatible with the host operating
>   system: [microsoft/dotnet:2.0-runtime-nanoserver-1709,
>   microsoft/dotnet:2.0-sdk-nanoserver-1709]. Update the Dockerfile to
>   specify a different base image.

When trying to do a test build on VSTS. The same project compiles fine on my local VS2017. This is a windows based container (at least it is locally and docker is running windows)

The VSTS build implies that perhaps it's targeting a linux container but i cannot see anywhere in VSTS to specify that.

But confused where i should be look at next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, for windows based container, you can use Hosted or Hosted VS 2017 agent.

Secondly, you can’t use nanoserver base image on Hosted agent (using Microsoft/dotnet:2.0-sdk).

Related thread: [Why is the “Build an image” step failing for Docker on Visual Studio Online?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50201406/why-is-the-build-an-image-step-failing-for-docker-on-visual-studio-online)

Comment: Ah, yes. I'm actually using a console app for some number crunching so i don't think i need the nano server base anyway. I am using the Hosted/Hosted 2017 agent.

In the case of using a console app on top of core  on windows, what should i be using as the base image? Is there some guidance there? In VSTS there is no specific default set up for a console application it all looks like asp.net starting points so maybe i've got something wrong there...?

Comment: There are many docker images that you can use https://hub.docker.com/u/microsoft/, such as https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/dotnet-framework/